# Split Row into Mulitple Rows based on Value in Quantity Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a test table which contains Product information and a Quantity Column.

```
 ProdID = 1 Qty = 3
```

Where the Quantity is greater than 1, I need to generate the extra rows for the Quantity so output will only ever have Qty=1 against ever row:

```
 ProdID = 1 Qty = 1
 ProdID = 1 Qty = 1
 ProdID = 1 Qty = 1
```

I'm a bit stumped where to begin, I've thought about trying to add a row then reduce Qty each time but this will be looping, how can this be done as a Set operation... recrusive cte, cross apply, can it be done in tsql?

```
with cte_test
as
(select a.* from 
(values('01-JAN-19','PROD1','BLUE',10.00, 1)
  ,('01-JAN-19','PROD1','RED',10.00, 1)
  ,('02-JAN-19','PROD1','BLUE',10.00, 2)
  ,('02-JAN-19','PROD2','BLUE',10.00, 1)
  ,('03-JAN-19','PROD1','RED',20.00, 6)
  ,('04-JAN-19','PROD1','BLUE',10.00, 1)
  ,('04-JAN-19','PROD3','BLACK',10.00, 3)
  ,('05-JAN-19','PROD1','BLUE',10.00, 2)
) as a ([Date],[Product],[Colour],[Price],[Qty])
)

select [Date],[Product],[Colour],[Price],[Qty] 
from cte_test
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f71fd/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like recursive CTEs for this purpose:

```
with cte as (
      select [Date], [Product], [Colour], [Price], [Qty]
      from [TestTable]
      union all
      select [Date], [Product], [Colour], [Price], [Qty] - 1
      from cte
      where Qty > 1
     )
select [Date], [Product], [Colour], [Price], 1 as [Qty]
from cte;
```

If `Qty` is greater than 100, you need to add `option (maxrecursive 0)`.

Comment: So simple and an elegant solution. Would I have issues you think if it were to run on hundreds of thousands of rows...guess one way for me to find out, thinking about it, it will be how many of those rows are greater than 1

Comment: @RogerClerkwell . . . No.  Another reasonable solution is to use a numbers table.  However, you need to be sure that such a table is big enough for the largest number -- at least the recursive CTE will fail if the recursion option is not big enough.

Answer (score 1):

With a recursive CTE:

```
declare @maxqty int = (select max(qty) from [TestTable]);
with cte AS (
  select 1 qty
  union all
  select qty + 1 from cte where qty + 1 <= @maxqty
)
select [Date], [Product], [Colour], [Price], 1 as [Qty]
from [TestTable] t inner join cte c
on c.qty <= t.qty
order by [Date], [Product]
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=56c0fda87664d6ea472ce5eccb357a01).
Results:

```
> Date      | Product | Colour | Price | Qty
> :-------- | :------ | :----- | :---- | --:
> 01-JAN-19 | PROD1   | BLUE   | 10.00 |   1
> 01-JAN-19 | PROD1   | RED    | 10.00 |   1
> 02-JAN-19 | PROD1   | BLUE   | 10.00 |   1
> 02-JAN-19 | PROD1   | BLUE   | 10.00 |   1
> 02-JAN-19 | PROD2   | BLUE   | 10.00 |   1
> 03-JAN-19 | PROD1   | RED    | 10.00 |   1
> 03-JAN-19 | PROD1   | RED    | 10.00 |   1
> 03-JAN-19 | PROD1   | RED    | 10.00 |   1
> 03-JAN-19 | PROD1   | RED    | 10.00 |   1
> 03-JAN-19 | PROD1   | RED    | 10.00 |   1
> 03-JAN-19 | PROD1   | RED    | 10.00 |   1
> 04-JAN-19 | PROD1   | BLUE   | 10.00 |   1
> 04-JAN-19 | PROD3   | BLACK  | 10.00 |   1
> 04-JAN-19 | PROD3   | BLACK  | 10.00 |   1
> 04-JAN-19 | PROD3   | BLACK  | 10.00 |   1
> 05-JAN-19 | PROD1   | BLUE   | 10.00 |   1
> 05-JAN-19 | PROD1   | BLUE   | 10.00 |   1
```